# Android app icon with image + text?

Tags: android, icons, launcher, hindi

Let me specify the problem first.
My app is designed for text mainly in Hindi, and I want to target Android OS below 4.1, which doesn't support hindi characters(yes, I've tried various Hindi fonts, which don't work properly, or the desired outcome is not the expected one).

So, I've prepared icons with hindi text, and all works perfectly fine now.

The problem left with is, how can I specify hindi text for the launcher icon?
I've tried to specify hindi text by creating an image with hindi text, and left the application:label ="" and activity:label="" blank.
But the text doesn't appear in where the app name should have appeared, or apparently I didn't create the image correctly.
Any help in this regard would be appreciated :)

Comment: The fallback option is always to specify the app name in English, but it would be good if I can have the name in hindi, as that is the USP of my app :)
Moreover, I would have wanted to specify hindi text for Android 4.1 or above, if there was any way to modify the manifest file based on OS version somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already have tried [Krutidev](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://in.ffonts.net/Kruti-Dev-010.font.download&ei=pEPIUsO2OcH_rQfk5IHwDw&usg=AFQjCNFFIY5kEzpY7Ru0DdkfM8Wfz6ZPjw&sig2=3_DBkhaDzOe6tK5j3Ca4hw&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bmk.) (Hindi Font), if not you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Though it may late to answer now, but as i read this now, i would like to answer since I did the same in my application in the following way:
1. Just in application tag of your app's manifest, give app name as normal:
android:label="@string/app_name"
2. in resource file strings.xml, add a string 'app_name' with the name your want for your app. Be careful, what i did was: i typed the text using Google transliteration and i gave this in Hindi.
3. Then when you save your strings.xml, it will ask you to save this in proper encoding, then choose 'utf-8', and that's it.